# My client code makes my android app crash

Tags: java, android, java.util.scanner, outputstream, datainputstream

So I have this client code which I tested in `Eclipse` and it works there

```java
try {
    // Establish connection
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.104"), 9000);

    // Request data
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    msg = "IDGN:" + "1";
    System.out.println(msg);

    outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    socket.shutdownOutput();
    scanner = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    restaurante = scanner.readUTF();
    System.out.println(restaurante);

    // Shut down socket
    socket.shutdownInput();
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I try to do the same in an Android app it crashes

```java
try {
    // Establish connection
    Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.104"), 9000);

    // Request data
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

    msg = "IDGN:" + "1";
    outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    socket.shutdownOutput();

    scanner = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    restaurante = scanner.readUTF();

    View b = findViewById(R.id.texto);
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String ss = "Valore el servicio recibido en: " + restaurante;
    ((TextView) b).setText(ss);

    // Shut down socket
    socket.shutdownInput();
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
```

I just don't know why and I have tried to make it wait for the data to be ready, to change it to `OutputStream` and read a line from a scanner, to read the bytes directly from the `OutputStream`.

The Server seems to be receiving the Data fine in both cases (Android and Eclipse) and sending the correct answer.

Comment: and *what* exception do you get? can you share a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have both network I/O and UI operations such as `TextView#setText()` in the same thread. Attempting to do network I/O on UI thread results in `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Attempting to do UI operations on non-UI thread results in `CalledFromWrongThreadException`. Guess your code is crashing on one of these.

There are some advanced mechanism for threading such as rxjava schedulers or kotlin coroutines. Without adding additional library dependencies you could experiment moving your network code to an `AsyncTask`.

See also:

[How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Thanks, this totally worked, I ended up using two different threads and joining them just for testing, might change it to an AssyncTask later.

Answer (score 0):

Close or flush the output stream when you are done. I think it is causing memory leakage in app